# How can I construct a nested dictionary object based on a delimited string?

Tags: python, dictionary

I would like to make a dictionary from python string as described below:

`'a/b/c/d/e' -> {a : {b : {c : {d : {e : {}}}}}}`

How can i achieve this easily?

Comment: i have no exaxt idea how should  i do it :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple way is, split the string based on `/` and then use `reduce` function to create a new dictionary every time a key is processed, like this

```
>>> data, result = 'a/b/c/d/e', {}
>>> reduce(lambda x, y: x.setdefault(y, {}), data.split("/"), result)
{}
>>> result
{'a': {'b': {'c': {'d': {'e': {}}}}}}
```

Whenever `dict.setdefault` is invoked, a new dictionary object is assigned to the current key, `y` and the new dictionary will be returned and it will be used as the `x` value in the next iteration.